# How do check the Css properties for an element when pressed in Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Google Chrome Developer Kit, I have a button with some CSS style applied, I need to see the properties associated on this status Hover in Googel Chrome Devoper windows.

How to do it? When I move out from the button change status and I cannot see the CSS applied.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inspect element, there are a couple of icons top right ...

[image]

Click the one as in the image (pointer) and select the states for your element with the checkboxes.